# How do I see what JS is changing style to my elements in Chrome dev tools or Firefox dev tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

My is a noob question as I am just learning JS so I am not good at it yet.

I am currently building a website ad added some JS snippets to do few actions. Now my footer has `opacity: 0` and it doesn't come from CSS, therefore must come from some JS, but I cannot find it. How do I find what JS is modifying the style of a specific HTML element in the Chrome or Firefox DevTools?

Here is a screenshot to show the code:
[image: https://imgur.com/iYIeSPO]

I checked all my JS files but couldn't find anything that gives my footer `opacity:0`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Chrome DevTools allow you to stop at a specific change in the DOM structure.

To do that right click the element and choose *Break on* > *attribute modifications* from the context menu.

[image: Break on attribute modifications]

Then, once the `style` attribute is added (may require a page reload), the script execution will stop at the JavaScript line where the change occurred.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't see which part of the code is changing the style.

Try setting breakpoints to find out where it sets it.

Maybe it isn't in your js files? It could be a script element in the document

Comment: I use Brackets and searched for opacity: 0 in in Find in Files but found nothing that gives it to the footer. So must be coming from some external script. I will study how to set breakpoints. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent that from happening, you can add a small `<script>` tag to the end of your `.html` file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <footer class="footer" style="opacity: 0;">My footer </footer>
</body>

</html>
<script>
  /* Place this script tag at the end of your document */
  document.getElementsByClassName("footer")[0].style.opacity = 1; //sets opacity of footer element to 1
</script>
```

If you really want to check what is changing your `style` attribute, you can check these guides from [chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints) and [firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger-API/Tutorial-Breakpoint) on how to set breakpoints in devtools.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I added the script after the closing HTML but still doesn't work. I will check the guides and hope I can find the problem with those. Thank you